# How to compare two JSON fields in RestAssured and Hamcrest?

Tags: rest-assured, hamcrest

I'm using RestAssured and Hamcrest to functional test our Back-end API and I'd like to know if there's any way to compare two distinct JSON fields inside the `body` method, or any equivalent.

For example, given the JSON response below:

```json
[
  { name: "Foo", age: 25 },
  { name: "Bar", age: 30 }
]
```

And given the code below, with a little excerpt of an invalid source code line that exposes what I'm trying to achieve:

```java
given()
  .when()
  .get("/my-endpoint")
  .then()
  .body("[0].age", lessThan("[1].age")); // Invalid code just to show what I need to do
```

How can I achieve the goal exposed above in a clean way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the best way of doing it. It's quite simple actually.
I just need to:

```java
given()
  .when()
  .get("/my-endpoint")
  .then()
  .body("[0].age", resp -> lessThan(resp.path("[1].age"));
```